# Adding placeholder to dynamically created elements by JS in IE8

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have the below code to show a form for admin to create, suspend accounts

```
echo "<FORM name=\"admin\" action=\"\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">";
echo "<select onchange=\"ChangeType();\" name=\"action\" id=\"action\">";
echo "<option value=\"select\">--Select--</option>";
echo "<option value=\"create\">Create Account</option>";
echo "<option value=\"suspend\">Suspend Account</option>";
echo "</select><br><br>";
echo "<div id=\"data\">";
echo "</div>";
echo "<input type=\"button\" name=\"button\" onclick=\"AccountAction()\" value=\"Submit\">";
echo "<input type=\"reset\" id=\"reset\" value=\"Reset\" onclick=\"ResetForm();\">";
echo "</FORM>";
```

and the javascript to dynamically create elements within the DOM when the user calls ChangeType()

```
function ChangeType()
{
    var type = document.getElementById("action").options[document.getElementById("action").selectedIndex].value;
    if(type=="select")
    {
        document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = "";
    }
    if(type=="create")
    {
        document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = "<input id=\"username\" placeholder=\"Username\" type=\"text\" name=\"username\"><br><br>";
        document.getElementById('data').innerHTML += "<input id=\"password\" placeholder=\"Password\" type=\"password\" name=\"password\"><br><br>";
        return;
    }
    if(type=="suspend")
    {
        document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = "<input id=\"username\" placeholder=\"Username\" type=\"text\" name=\"username\"><br><br>";
        return;
    }
}
```

the code works fine however i cannot get the placeholder for the dynamically created username and password input types

i have already looked at
[Adding jQuery placeholders to dynamically created form elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163872/adding-jquery-placeholders-to-dynamically-created-form-elements)

but it doesn't help as the placeholders only appear when i click within the textarea once and then click outside.

Comment: Why did you tag this jQuery?

Comment: i thought there is a way to do this in jquery so maybe someone from jquery can provide a working solution to add a placeholder in IE8 for dynamic elements created in JS

Comment: a good place to find polyfills for html5 features in general is [here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-forms--input-placeholder)

Comment: Please don't abuse `placeholder` like that: [The placeholder attribute should not be used as an alternative to a label.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute)

Comment: then you have to use jquery as it is browser independent. check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

> You have to do like this :

```
document.getElementById('data').setAttribute("placeholder", "placeholder value");
```

> In your code :

```
function ChangeType() {
var type = document.getElementById("action").options[document.getElementById("action").selectedIndex].value;
if (type == "select") {
    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('data').setAttribute("placeholder", "placeholder value");
}
if (type == "create") {
    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = "<input id=\"username\" placeholder=\"Username\" type=\"text\" name=\"username\"><br><br>";
    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML += "<input id=\"password\" placeholder=\"Password\" type=\"password\" name=\"password\"><br><br>";
    document.getElementById('data').setAttribute("placeholder", "placeholder value");
    return;
}
if (type == "suspend") {
    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = "<input id=\"username\" placeholder=\"Username\" type=\"text\" name=\"username\"><br><br>";
    document.getElementById('data').setAttribute("placeholder", "placeholder value");
    return;
}}
```

> Using Jquery (browser compatible solution) :

```
$("#data").attr("placeholder", "placeholder value");
```

Comment: then you have to use jquery as it is browser independent. check my updated answer.

Comment: i have tried using the jQuery code and that still doesnt work with IE8

Comment: @MotaChuha: Since IE8 does not have native `placeholder` support, setting the placeholder attribute won't have any effect (with or without jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

**HTML**

```
<FORM name="admin" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <select onchange="ChangeType();" name="action" id="action">
    <option value="select">--Select--</option>
    <option value="create">Create Account</option>
    <option value="suspend">Suspend Account</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <div id="data"></div>
    <input type="button" name="button" onclick="AccountAction()" value="Submit">
    <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" onclick="ResetForm();">
    <!--This button alerts all palceholder attributes for all input tags within the div-->
    <input type="button" name="button" onclick="checkPlaceHolder()" value="Check Placeholder Values">
</FORM>
```

**Javascript**

```
function AccountAction(){}
function ResetForm(){}

function ChangeType() {
    var type = document.getElementById("action").options[document.getElementById("action").selectedIndex].value;
    if(type=="select")
    {
        document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = "";
    }
    if(type=="create")
    {
        document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = "<input id=\"username\" placeholder=\"Username\" type=\"text\" name=\"username\"><br><br>";
        document.getElementById('data').innerHTML += "<input id=\"password\" placeholder=\"Password\" type=\"password\" name=\"password\"><br><br>";
        return;
    }
    if(type=="suspend")
    {
        document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = "<input id=\"username\" placeholder=\"Username\" type=\"text\" name=\"username\"><br><br>";
        return;
    }
}

function checkPlaceHolder() {
    $( '#data input' ).each(function(o) {
        alert('Placeholder : ' + $(this).attr('placeholder'));
    });
}
```

The function `checkPlaceHolder` alerts all the input tag placeholder attributes within the `div` tag. Hope this helps.

Comment: the problem when i select the option from the dropdown it shows the input elements however placeholders are not visible. when i click inside the input box and then click outside it is visible then

Comment: Even i faced errors on jsfiddle. I am seeing the placeholders when i run the code on my local m/c. Which browser are you trying? `placeholder` is an html5 attribute.

Comment: it works fine in IE10, FF and chrome however i want it to work on IE8 since we officially support IE8

Comment: `IE8` does not support `placeholders`. To do that, you may want to use this plugin - https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder